# delete duplicate elements in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a large file and have found that some elements are in it twice, now I would like to delete the duplicates. any ideas what I could do? Would appreciate any help!

The xml looks like this:

```
<Toptag>
<text coordinates="" country="" date="yyyy-mm-dd" lang="" place="xyc" time="" id=" 123"  name="xyz" >
<div>
This is text
</div>
</text>
<text coordinates="" country="" date="yyyy-mm-dd" lang="" place="xyc" 
time="" id=" 124"  name="xyz" >
<div>
This is text
</div>
</text>
<text coordinates="" country="" date="yyyy-mm-dd" lang="" place="xyc"         time="" id=" 123"  name="xyz" >
<div>
This is text
</div>
</text>
....
</toptag>
```

In the duplicates, everything from `<text...............> <div> </div> </text>`  is exactly the same!

Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use at least XSLT 2 you have access to the `deep-equal` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal and can therefore write an empty template

```
  <xsl:template match="Toptag/text[some $sib in preceding-sibling::text satisfies deep-equal(., $sib)]"/>
```

together with the identity transformation (e.g. in XSLT 3 using the appropriate `xsl:mode` declaration or in XSLT 2 by spelling it out):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Toptag/text[some $sib in preceding-sibling::text satisfies deep-equal(., $sib)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that way those `text` elements that have a preceding sibling `text` that is deep equal are not copied: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzF

Obviously the condition in the predicate could be adjusted to check all preceding nodes as well.

Comment: The OP says it's a large file: this is going to be O(n^2) which isn't great.

Comment: Guess I need to take that XSLT performance course at XML summer school first before dreaming up elegantly looking stuff on StackOverflow. Someone I read often uses to say to us to worry only about performance if it turns out to be a problem so lets hear what the poster says.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works really well on the smaller files... it takes forever (I had to cancel it before it finished) on the larger files (500mb-1gb).
Thanks again!

Comment: @mynamehere, which XSLT processor and version exactly do you use? As Michael Kay has pointed out, my suggestion above looking at the siblings doesn't work well with large files, you will need to try to implement his suggestion, although with 1GB large files depending on your system you can hit the limits of traditional, tree based XSLT anyway.

Comment: @mynamehere,  I have tried to implement Mike's suggestion yesterday at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzF/1, although it is a hack as I have simply used `serialize` instead of a custom fingerprint function that ensure you get the same order for attributes. Perhaps it helps you molding his suggestion into a working solution for your big files.

Comment: At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzF/2 I have tried the suggestion by Michael Kay to use a function to compute a signature or fingerprint based on attributes and string contents. That way with the input in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTzF/3 it also eliminates duplicates having the same attributes but in different order which the `serialize` attempt would not catch, even if we hope that for the same lexical order like in your original sample we get the same serialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you can define a function f:signature(element(text)) that returns the same value for two elements if and only if they are considered equal, then you can use XSLT 2.0 grouping to eliminate the duplicates:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="text" group-by="f:signature(.)">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

If the elements have very different structure then writing a signature function might be difficult. But if they are all very similar, as your example seems to suggest, then you could use, for example

```
<xsl:function name="f:signature" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="e" as="element(text)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="string-join($e!(@coordinates, @country, @date, @lang, @place, string(.)), '|')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Note: I used the XSLT 3.0 "!" operator because you don't want the attributes sorted into document order (document order of attributes is unpredictable). In 2.0, where "!" isn't available, you can spell it out as `($e/@coordinates, $e/@country, $e/@date, ...)`.

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to run it with an XSLT 1.0 processor. When things don't work, we usually can't help you unless you explain the failure symptoms.